# Illegal string offset 'child_field' in array

Tags: php, arrays, woocommerce

First of all, I'm still a newbie when it comes to array. Why am I getting the error `Illegal string offset 'child_field'`?

This is my code.

```
$product_extras = $cart_item['product_extras'];

foreach ( $product_extras as $product_extra ) {
    if ( $product_extra['child_field'] == 1 ) {
            echo "YES";
    }
}
```

This is the array

```
Array
(
    [products] => Array
        (
            [pewc_parent_product] => 8928
            [parent_field_id] => pewc_5d66c506a5bb6
            [child_field] => 1
            [pewc_group_8929_9028_child_field] => pewc_group_8929_9028
            [products_quantities] => one-only
            [allow_none] => 0
        )

    [product_id] => 8945
    [title] => Section 200
    [groups] => Array
        (
        )

)
[28-Aug-2019 21:49:47 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'child_field' in C:\laragon\www\xxxxx\wp-content\plugins\xxxxx\inc\class-woocommerce.php on line 129
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a nested array.  So in the `foreach` loop, it first looks at the `[products]` element (which is an array), and yes, you have a `[child_field]` element.  Then it looks at the next element, which is `[product_id]`, and you do not have the `[child_field]` subelement.  Thus the error.

To fix:

```
 if ( isset($product_extra['child_field']) && $product_extra['child_field'] == 1 )
```

Comment: Alternately, you could do this:  `foreach ( $product_extras['products'] as $product_extra )`

Answer (score 0):

Your should remove the foreach, and use this if

```
if(1 == $product_extra["products"]['child_field']){
    echo "YES";
}
```